# Create navigation breadcrumb using an XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Not sure if this is possible. I have an XML file that is used to build the Navigation Menu (Programmatically built using UL/LI). The Website has 2 sections. Left side has the Navigation Menu and Right Panel has a IFrame that displays the file from navigation menu.

Can I use the same XML file to build the navigation breadcrumb?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.  If your XML file has the proper urls and the proper text.